# Testing authentication in Django Rest Framework Views -- Cannot authenticate when testing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

After struggling mightily with this issue, I've come asking for a bit of help. I'm writing a test for a Django Rest Framework view, testing whether or not I can access the data whilst authenticated, and not. However, even when I'm authenticated, I still get `401 UNAUTHORIZED` every time. Here's my tests:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory, APIClient

from apps.core import models, admin
from apps.rest import views


class TestAPIViews(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('testuser', email='testuser@test.com', password='testing')
        self.user.save()
        token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)
        token.save()

    def _require_login(self):
        self.client.login(username='testuser', password='testing')

    def test_ListAccounts_not_authenticated(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/accounts/')
        view = views.ListAccounts.as_view()
        response = view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 401,
            'Expected Response Code 401, received {0} instead.'.format(response.status_code))

    def test_ListAccounts_authenticated(self):
        self.client._require_login()
        print(self.user.is_authenticated()) # returns True
        request = self.factory.get('/accounts/')
        view = views.ListAccounts.as_view()
        response = view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200,
            'Expected Response Code 200, received {0} instead.'.format(response.status_code))
```

And here is the code for my DRF View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db.models import Q


from apps.core import serializers, models
from apps.rest.permissions import IsAccountOwner

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status, authentication, generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

from apps.core import serializers, models

'''
Auth Mixin for Account Admin Access
'''
class AuthMixin:
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,
                              authentication.SessionAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class GenericList(AuthMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Stubbed out - doing nothing special right now
        qs = self.model.objects.filter()
        return qs


class ListAccounts(GenericList):
    model = models.Account
    serializer_class = serializers.AccountSerializer
```

As one can see, I'm calling login in the `test_ListAccounts_authenticated`, and then printing out whether or not I'm authenticated (Which returns `True`), but I get a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` Error no matter what. Anything I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but your AuthMixin doesn't subclass anything, should probably by `AuthMixin(object)`. Other than that it looks ok. I've got the SessionAuthentication as the first item, not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: The AuthMixin is just a class that I created. It doesn't and shouldn't subclass anything.

Comment: @Fiver, it probably does matter, not sure why, but when I did put (SessionAuthentication as first - It was not included) that I resolved the authentication issues I was having on test.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of calling `self.factory.get()`, call `self.client.get()`.

I'm guessing `self.client.login` has no effect on `self.factory`.